# exposed filter result : how to check the results is lesser than 20 or greater than 20...?

Tags: views

i have created the content type named candidate_profile, included fields like Current_Salary_Range and  i have created a view named display_candidate and also i am using better exposed filter for current_salary_range field the filtered the result print in view throw the Header->Global:Result summary.hence how should i proceed to check the results is lesser than 20 or greater than 20...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the below code to check the result is greater than or lesser than 20

global $pager_total_items;
  print $pager_total_items[0] ;

if($pager_total_items[0]>20)
  {
    print 'Result is greater than 20';
  } 
  else 
  {
    print 'Result is lesser than 20';
  }

In this code put into your theme folder like mytheme/templates/page.tpl.php file.

but this is working only that particular theme because of i write that code into mytheme page.tpl.php file thats why...